kdb/q How to get Net Totals and Label each row categorically?
This is what my table looks like:



Name
Region
Code
Type
Neg2
Neg1
Day0
Pos1
Pos2




Bob
AA
1A
Buy
100
1
1
80
30


Bob
AA
1A
Sell
-30
-2
-1
-10
-10


Ann
ER
5D
Sell
-60
-3
-1
-4
-10


Art
AA
WA
Buy
300
4
1
300
300


Art
AA
WA
Sell
-500
-5
-1
-100
-100



a: ([] Name:`Bob`Bob`Ann`Art`Art; Region:`AA`AA`ER`AA`AA; Code: `1A`1A`5D`WA`WA; Type: `Buy`Sell`Sell`Buy`Sell; Neg2: 100 -30 -60 300 -500; Neg1: 1 -2 -3 4 -5; Day0: 1 -1 -1 1 -1; Pos1: 80 -10 -4 300 -100; Pos2: 30 -10 -10 300 -100)

Where the first 4 columns are categorical variables, and the rest are amounts either bought or sold for 2 days before, after, and during Day0.
What I want is to sum each row by Name, Region, Code, and Type to get the quantities bought/sold before and after/on Day0:
a: update preday0: Neg2 + Neg1 by Name, Region, Code, Type from a;
a: update postday0: Day0 + Pos1 + Pos2 by Name, Region, Code, Type from a;




Name
Region
Code
Type
Neg2
Neg1
Day0
Pos1
Pos2
preday0
postday0




Bob
AA
1A
Buy
100
1
1
80
30
101
111


Bob
AA
1A
Sell
-30
-2
-1
-10
-10
-32
-21


Ann
ER
5D
Sell
-60
-3
-1
-4
-10
-63
-15


Art
AA
WA
Buy
300
4
1
300
300
304
601


Art
AA
WA
Sell
-500
-5
-1
-100
-100
-505
-201



Then, I want to get the Net Amounts, grouping by Name, Region and Code. This is what I am struggling to get:



Name
Region
Code
Type
Neg2
Neg1
Day0
Pos1
Pos2
preday0
postday0
neg
post




Bob
AA
1A
Buy
100
1
1
80
30
101
111
buy
buy


Bob
AA
1A
Sell
-30
-2
-1
-10
-10
-32
-21
buy
buy


Ann
ER
5D
Sell
-60
-3
-1
-4
-10
-63
-15
sell
sell


Art
AA
WA
Buy
300
4
1
300
300
304
601
sell
buy


Art
AA
WA
Sell
-500
-5
-1
-100
-100
-505
-201
sell
buy



For example, Bob-AA-1A has two line items, but before Day 0 it was a net positive (101 + -32) and same with after/on Day 0 (111 + -21), so I would have both neg and post values be `buy for the first 2 rows.
Ann-ER-5D would have both sells as there's only one column and they both net negtaive.
Art-AA-WA would have net sell for pre and bet buy for post, because the preday0 total sums to a negative amount, and postday0 sums to a positive for the two bottom rows.
How can I implement this? Or, is there a more elegant solution with the initial table?

There's some confusing things in your data that make it hard to help you. You have a neg2 of -500 in your displays but your sample code has a -100 in that spot. Also, why does "Art" have a different neg output for each row in your final display? Shouldn't it be the same once it's aggregated?

Fixed those issues, thanks

Based on your updates, I think what you're trying to achieve at the end is:
q)a:update Neg:?[0<sum preday0;`buy;`sell] by Name,Region,Code from a;
q)a:update Post:?[0<sum postday0;`buy;`sell] by Name,Region,Code from a;

There could be many other ways to get to this solution but this approach is fine if it works for you (there won't be any approach that's massively more efficient than this)
